# Twitter api: Does x follow y?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm looking for a very simple script that will tell me if one twitter user follows another twitter user. I looked through the twitter developer docs, but I couldn't find any information relating to what I want to accomplish.

An example of what I'm looking for is demonstrated on this site:
http://doesfollow.com/jjmpsp/rhyyysss

I did consider using this website, and then checking if the page contains the string "yup", but obviously this isn't the most efficient way to do this.

Anyone have any suggestions/resources to how I could go about accomplishing what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Lol...

https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/show.json?source_screen_name=jjmpsp&target_screen_name=Rhyyysss